# Recursive sql query n to n in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursive-query

I have a database table like that

```
Table student
_______________
id_student int (PK)
student_name VARCHAR
```

and I have a recursive loop: 
A student can oversee many students, and a student can be overseen by many students
so a new table:

```
Table oversee
________________
id_student pk, fk 
id_overseen pk, fk
date date
```

the problem is that I want to get the list that I have
I made an sql query:

```
with 
sr1 as ( select s.student_name as over from student s, oversee o where o.id_student = s.id_student),
sr2 as (select s.student_name as overseen from student s, oversee o where o.id_overseen = s.id_student)
select distinct * from sr1, sr2;
```

the problem is that's the query returns the wrong answers
I mean if we have two lines in the table, it will return 4 lines.
I want to get every student with his overseen:
Student | overseen.
Someone has any idea please?
Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what you want query to return. You sure didn't write any recursive logic anywhere.

Comment: SQL is a language but different databases implement parts of the language differently, so what database are you using (re-tag your question appropriately).

Comment: @Andreas I want to get a table with student | overseen | date

Comment: @Sentinel I'm using SQLITE

Comment: That's a simple `JOIN`, and doesn't need `WITH` at all.

Comment: You should provide sample data and the expected results along with the query you've already provided.  You query has a cross product (theta join) between sr1 and sr2.

Comment: @Sentinel I want to get a table that returns every student with the students that are overseeing him.
Student | overseen

Comment: @Andreas you sure? I tried it before.

Comment: @Sentinel 
Student1 is overseeing student 2 and student3
Student2 is overseen by student1 and student 4
the table must return 
student1 | student2
student1 | student3
student4 | student 2

Comment: Don't clarify question in comments. Edit the question to clarify it. Delete the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get a table with `student | overseen | date`

```
SELECT s.student_name AS student
     , s2.student_name AS overseen
     , oversee.date
  FROM student s
  JOIN oversee ON oversee.id_student = s.id_student
  JOIN student s2 ON s2.id_student = oversee.id_overseen
```

Comment: I don't think it's working, that returns every student in the database

Comment: @Devweb If you don't want the students that are not overseen, remove the two `LEFT` keywords.